# How can I test that a docker wordpress-fpm with custom plugins works

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, docker, cgi

I have made The following Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:fpm

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y unzip &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*

ENV PLUGIN_URL https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin

ENV PIWIK_PLUGIN_VERSION 1.0.9
RUN curl -o /tmp/wp-piwik.${PIWIK_PLUGIN_VERSION}.zip  ${PLUGIN_URL}/wp-piwik.${PIWIK_PLUGIN_VERSION}.zip &&\
    unzip /tmp/wp-piwik.${PIWIK_PLUGIN_VERSION}.zip -d /tmp &&\
    chown www-data:www-data /tmp/wp-piwik &&\
    mv /tmp/wp-piwik /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/&&\
    find /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-piwik -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + &&\
    find /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-piwik -type d -exec chmod 633 {} + &&\  
    ls -l  /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/
```

But as you can see it runs fpm. Also on my host  have installed a lamp stack with php that does NOT run on fpm. So I want my installed apache to be able to connect to my a running fpm container from the above dockerfile.

What I want to achieve it to test that the plugin I installed manually during the build works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I switched this:

```
FROM wordpress:fpm
```

Into this:

```
FROM wordpress
```

So I can test directly with my browser via docker's port forwarding